# Specify font size of javascript alert box message

Tags: javascript, fonts

I have to show the message on alert box with font size - 6. I have done like below.

```
     var str = "Formatting some text.";
     str = str.fontsize("6").fontcolor("#006400").bold();
     alert(str);
```

But the output get as
`<b><font color="#006400"><font size="6">Formatting some text.</font></font></b>`
Please help to correct the issue

Comment: I don't think alert's text could be styled.

Comment: what library uses font tags? yikes.

Comment: Do you mean `6px`?

Comment: @guest271314  yes 6px

Comment: It is possible to set bold text. Have not found a way to resize text using `javascript`.

Comment: It's 2017, don't use the thread-blocking 1998 `alert()` function to show your users a warning. Especially if you're **not** showing them a warning but just want to show them a piece of text without anything having gone wrong. Use any of the million of vanilla JS, jQuery, etc. etc. dialog solutions instead. You even have an answer that gives you the code that. Use that, don't use `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

I think No as per my knowledge as this is controlled by the browser

You would have to use a JavaScript based dialog windows alternative like [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

there is another alternative to jQuery UI Dialog box is [sweetalert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert)

Comment: @guest271314 You can not control the size of the text with window alert.... So not sure what you are hinting at.

Comment: I removed it, sorry

Comment: @epascarello It is possible to set bold text at `alert()` call, which is a portion of original Question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set bold text at `alert()`

```js
alert("  .")
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7YgLB/10/

Answer (score -1):

Use this code. It will help

### HTML

```
<div id="Custom_Alert" title="Alert">
  <p style="font-size:6px">Formatting some text.</p>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$( function() {
  $( "#Custom_Alert" ).dialog();
} );
```

Comment: it's 2017, `<font>` is not a real HTML tag and hasn't been since 1998. Set some CSS style on the `<p>` element instead.